# How can root@% grant a user to select all entries in information_schema.Tables

Tags: mysql, information-schema

MySQL 5.7.24

After creating a user, it can

```
select count(*) from information_schema.Tables
```

and get 50, let's say.
And root@% can get 300 with the same SQL.

how can root@% grant the created user to select all entries in information_schema.Tables.

if I

```
grant select on information_schema.Tables to test_user;
```

it says:

```
1044 - Access denied for user 'root'@'%' to database 'information_schema'
```

So, I want to know, how to grant the created user privileges on information_schema.